# Seeking custom/chat log analyzer

Tags: logging, analyzer

I have a flash chat program that outputs chat logs that are nearly impossible to view without processing.  I've spent quite awhile looking for a windows program (preferably) that will take the following type of data and output it in a human readable format:

```
<r>ROOMNAME</r><f>USERID-From</f><to>USERID-to</to><w>WHISPER-false</w><dt>1.340758262E9</dt><c><![CDATA[how are you?]]></c></m><m>
```

Comment: Have you tried asking the chat program developer for one? If the program isn't widely known your easiest solution might be to write a small parser yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> the following type of data and output it in a human readable format

I suppose it's a little subjective, what's "human readable." SGML/XML in general are designed to be just that.  But here are some suggestions:

- [`xmllint`](https://code.google.com/p/xmllint/) has a pretty-printer
- XPath is a really great way to pluck specific content from an XML file.  Use your favorite language's XPath support (JAXP for Java, libxml for python, etc).
- A pretty-printing example of some Java source, from http://ig2600.blogspot.com/2009/12/pretty-printing-xml-on-windows.html:

Here's the example:

```
namespace xmllint
{
    using System;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.Linq;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var xml = XDocument.Parse(Console.In.ReadToEnd());
            var output = new XmlTextWriter(Console.Out);
            output.Indentation = 4;
            output.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            xml.WriteTo(output);
            output.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, in case it wasn't already obvious, the '`dt`' tag contains a floating point representation of seconds since the epoch.